# BGE Add object action deforms a sphere mesh

Tags: mesh, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have watched Blender Game Engine Basics Tutorial #24: Shooting While Walking (Combining Actions) video tutorial from BornCG, but when I shoot the bullet (Left Ctrl key), it appears deformed.

[image]

The bullet is a regular sphere.

[image]

Could someone help me? I'll be glad for some comments.

Here my blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Opening up your file, your PlayerBound object has a scale of 1.28, 1.28, 3.70 on it.

Select PlayerBound, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then click scale to reset the scale to 1, 1, 1 without changing the geometry.

Right now your spheres are inheriting PlayerBound's scale, making them about 3 times as long as they are wide.